# Path variable not defined for a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to change the language of my application from a drop down menu followed by a submit button.
I introduced a controller named 'language_change' defined in the route.rb as:

```
resources :language_change, :only => [:create, :new]
```

In the view home.html.erb, I put it this way:

```
<%= form_tag language_change_path, :method=>:post do %>
<div class="field">
    <%= select_tag(params[:l],
       options_for_select(
      [[t('language.english'),'en'],
       [t('language.french'), 'fr'],
       [t('language.dutch'), 'nl']], params[:l]),
       )   
     %>  
 </div>
 <div class="actions"> <%= submit_tag "Change language!" %>
<% end %>
```

Finally in the controller I put:

```
class LanguageChangeController < ApplicationController
  def create
    I18n.locale=params[:l]
  end 
end
```

When loading the home page I get the following error message:

```
undefined local variable or method `language_change_path'
```

Does anybody can tell me what is wrong?
What I don't understand is when in the view I replace the 'language_change_path' by another controller defined elsewhere in the app, eg. 'password_reset_path' it displays the page and even handle the submit.

Thanks for your helage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to change this line in `routes.rb`:

```
resources :language_change, :only => [:create, :new]
```

to this:

```
resource :language_change, :only => [:create, :new]
```

Otherwise, the helper method `language_change_path` is expecting a specific instance of `LanguageChange` to link to. By specifying the resource as singular, you don't need to pass an instance to the helper since it's required that only one such instance exists.

I'm guessing your `password_reset` resource is also singular.

Comment: Thanks Brandan! I now works but I had to pluralize also the name of my controller etc. It's good to know. Now I have to dig a bit further into the mystery of plurialization in ruby ;-)

Comment: Glad to help. Please make sure to accept the answer if it's correct.